# How to find sum of common terms in an A.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The question is :-

find the sum of first 200 terms appearing in both the A P.
1) 17, 21, 25, ...........
2) 16, 21, 26, ...........
If certain nos. appears in both the A.P.s

I searched everywhere, but i only found how to find no. of common terms but not their sum. Even this question has never been asked on this site before.

How to go about solving this question? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to describe how the common terms appear?  If you list them, do they look to be in a specific pattern? (*In particular are they in an arithmetic progression of their own?*)  Now that you know that, and you know how many terms are common to each (*from the searching you already did*) you can use your usual method to finding the sum of the first however many terms of an arithmetic progression to continue.

Comment: To recognize that it is indeed an arithmetic progression, the set of the numbers in the first AP can be recognized to be $\{x~:~ x\equiv 1\pmod{4}, 17\leq x\leq 17+199\cdot 4\}$ and for the second AP as $\{x~:~x\equiv 1\pmod{5}, 16\leq x\leq 16+199\cdot 5\}$.  The intersection of which can be found via the chinese remainder theorem as being those numbers which are $x\equiv 1\pmod{20}$ lying within a specific range.  So, the common numbers are $21,41,61,81,\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first term that appears in both of them is $21$.  Since $4$ and $5$ (the forward differences) are coprime, see that the sequences will only be equal every time the sequence increases by $4\times5=20$.

In other words,

$$21+41+61+81+\dots401=\sum_{n=1}^{200}20n+1=200(201)+200=200(202)=40400$$

Comment: I think he wants the sum of only the terms which appear in both of the sequences.